# SQL take part of text to update another field

Tags: t-sql

I have a field in my database called filename - it will always follow this format -
[BatchId]*[CompanyId]*[FinancialPeriod]

An example would be
001_100_201710

What I would like to do is from that string of text take the [BatchId] so whatever is before the first under score and update another field called Batch in the database. Not sure how to just get the Batch Id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls post query you tried...

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: string_spilt won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can split using something like this

```
DECLARE @filename as varchar(100)
set @filename = '001_100_201710' 

DECLARE @index INT 
set @index = CHARINDEX('_', @filename) 
select SUBSTRING(@filename, 0, @index ) BatchId
```